# nested handlebar helper throws error

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have registered two helpers with handlebar viz 'outer' and 'inner' and in my template I have as follows

```
{{#outer (inner data)}}
{{/outer}}
```

but some how the inner helper throws an error on console saying "options.inverse is not a function"

I am using  handlebars v3.0.3

Can someone tell me where I am making mistake.

I am using following code

```
Handlebars.registerhelper('outer',function(primary, options){
    If(primary){
        return options.fn(this);
     }else{
        return options.inverse(this);
     }
});

Handlebars.registerhelper('inner',function(primary, options){
    If(primary){
        return options.fn(this);
     }else{
        return options.inverse(this);
     }
});
```

Comment: Seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/465pys5x/

Comment: @nikoshr yeah but you haven't used options in the callback function. I am facing issue while using options.

Comment: Well, then edit your question to provide enough details to answer your question.

Comment: @nikoshr I have added the code the error is in else block of inner callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inverse` function is only present for [block helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html).

You are using outer as a block helper but inner as a regular one and that's why it fails only for the inner helper.

Comment: So is there any solution to this or do I need to modify my inner helper.

Comment: You need to modify your helper or your template depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.